# Difficult situation with domain under VestaCP

Tags: wordpress, dns, centos, vps

Let's say I have domain sxz.me.

Hostname is sxz.me, server is up and running. Unfortunately when I was typing in address sxz.me, it automatically redirected me to IP address 141.xxx.xx.xxx.

My point was to make it as domain name, not IP address. So I changed something in VestaCP that didn't work.

As a next idea, I have installed a plugin, which was redirecting IP address into sxz.me .. It worked! It started redirecting 141.xxx.xx.xxx into sxz.me. The problem was that sxz.me still didn't work e.g. didn't read files uploaded through ftp.

Then I've got genius idea of resetting the server from hosting support. I did it and then for whatever reason WordPress admin panel from 141.xxx.xx.xxx stopped working. I couldn't access it.

I've changed everything in VestaCP in the way described in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WyeXE32vafY).

Before it was also changed similar, but some parts were missing. We were waiting for DNS propagation and unexpectedly sxz.me started working! Almost there, but problem was that I still couldn't copy files from 141.xxx.xx.xxx by plugin, because of no access to WP admin.

I know there are also different ways, but that was my first idea. In the meantime I've started installing WordPress according to config.php from zero on 141.xxx.xx.xxx and website gone again! It just crashed somehow and started redirecting me once again to 141.xxx.xx.xxx so I'm completely confused and don't know what to do.

Domain doesn't work at all.

Comment: If you need any screenshots from anything just let me know..

Comment: Few are going to be able to decode this wall of text. [Edit] this question and tell us what you want to do, show what you have tried, and show what results you got. See [ask]. Also edit the question for readability, and make sure you provide a [mcve]. Unless you can show this is about some code you have written, this looks off-topic for SO.

Comment: This might be best researched over on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/